# Show that the order of the group is at least 33

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a$ and $b$ be in $G$ with $a$ of order 11 and $b$ of order 3. Show that the order of $G$ is at least 33. I'm trying to do this from first principles. Obviously with lagrange, it is immediate but how could I do it woithout using this?

Thanks

Comment: I think any proof "from first principles" would end up using Lagrange implicitly one way or another.

Comment: @angryavian I'm trying to help out with my brother's coursework, and from the questions it look like lagrange isn't assumed.

Comment: @angryavian: so hurrah for lhf's proof, which doesn't so much as mention group actions or partitions of G :-). And indeed it doesn't show the order of G is a multiple of 33, merely exhibits 33 distinct elements of G, so I reckon it's elementary for practical purposes.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, I was pleasantly surprised with his solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint:*

Consider the elements $a^i b^j$ for $i=1,\dots,11$ and $j=1,\dots,3$. Prove that they are all different.

*Solution:*

> If $a^i b^j = a^{k} b^{l}$, then $a^{i-k}=b^{l-j} \in A \cap B$, where $A=\langle a \rangle$ and $B=\langle b \rangle$. Now, $A \cap B= \{ e \}$ (see below), and so $a^i = a^{k}$ and $b^j = b^{l}$. Given the restrictions on the exponents, we must have $i=k$ and $j=l$.
>
>  To prove that $A \cap B=\{ e \}$, take $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A$ implies $x^{11}=e$ and $x \in B$ implies $x^{3}=e$ and so $x=x^1=x^{4\cdot3-1\cdot11}=(x^3)^4 (x^{11})^{-1}=e$.

Comment: good stuff thanks